# Как передать ByteBuffer в FFmpeg?

Tags: c++, видео, ffmpeg, mediaplayer

Я работаю с либой `FFmpeg` и здесь есть возможность передать путь к `mp4` файлу и прочитать его. Но я ищу возможность передать не путь к файлу, а передать уже извлеченный буфер байтов...

Странно, что у этой либы нет прямого метода это сделать, ведь под капотом она делает тоже самое, читает байты в буфер и декодирует их...

Кто стаскивался с этим подскажите возможные пути решения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ней есть прямой метод это сделать. Необходимо создать экземпляр класса `AVIOContext` посредством вызова `avio_alloc_context` задав делегаты для чтения / записи данных. Затем при создании экземпляра класса `AVFormatContext` присвоить указатель на ранее созданный экземпляр класса `AVIOContext` полю `AVFormatContext::pb`.

Comment: А есть какой то короткий пример? Очень мне помогло бы понять, что к чему

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Есть только длинный и не опенсорсный.